# How to install NDK with Android SDK Manager

Tags: android, windows, android-ndk, android-sdk-manager

It is said, that it is possible to install NDK with Android SDK manager with the following picture:

[image]

Unfortunately, I don't have `SDK Plantforms`, `SDK Tools` and `SDK Update Sites` tabs in my SDK Manager. My picture is following:

[image]

So how to install NDK in my situation?

Answer (score 15):

Since you are using the standalone Android SDK Manager, you'll need to use the [sdkmanager command line tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html).

1. Close **Android SDK Manager**
2. Start a **Command Prompt** as Administrator
3. `cd`*"path to your installation of Android SDK Manager"*`\tools\bin`
4. `sdkmanager ndk-bundle`
5. Accept the License Agreement
6. Wait a long time. The installation is done without any progress indicator.
7. When it finally reports `done`, start **Android SDK Manager**
8. Look under **Extras** and there you'll find **Ndk Bundle**

Comment: how to specify version of ndk?! https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile/ only accepts n21, you can't just do `sdkmanager ndk-bundle`

Comment: @user924 It was a long time since I dealt with the Android SDK manager but something like `sdkmanager --install "ndk;21.3.6528147" --channel=3` could work. That's an example from the [sdkmanager](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager) documentation.

Answer (score 3):

The android's standalone sdk manager [second picture] differs from the one integrated in Android Studio[first picture]. The standalone has the basics for android developing whereas the Android Studio's integrated sdk manager, located in Tools > Android > SDK Manager, adds more useful tools, such as the ndk, Cmake* and LLDB* [* in android studio 222 version] (the ones highlighted).

So you have two options, if you are using Android Studio, using the integrated sdk manager to directly install the ndk or you could manually download the [ndk](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html) and add the path to your system variables so your build environment is aware of it.

Answer (score 2):

If your internet connection is using a proxy, which is most often the case for office networks, the https connection to the Android repo does not work sometimes. As a result you will not see the NDK in the list. If that is the case, copy the https repo link and add the same repo with http, as shown on the picture.
[image: Screenshot of fix]

The "Custom Update Site" is the link that manually added repo link. Notice the change from https to http.

Answer (score 1):

@ortisenderos has the right options available to you.

If you're not going to utilize the common setups in android studio and/or eclipse you can expect to place the paths to all your tools into your PATH environment variable, (be it Linux, macOS or Windows).

```
[Path to CMake]/bin
[Path to Git]/bin
[Path to SDK]/tools
[Path to SDK]/platform-tools
[Path to NDK]
[Path to ANT]/bin
```

etc...

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways to install NDK with `sdkmanager` from command line:

Preferred method (will install specific NDK version at sdk/ndk/[version])

```
sdkmanager "ndk;26.1.10909125"
```

Legacy method (will install older NDK version [22.1.7171670] at sdk/ndk-bundle)

```
sdkmanager "ndk-bundle"
```

Second method seems obsolete and not documented, but might be useful for some old projects.