# Make cannot find android NDK when building openCV for android - how to set it up?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, cmake, android-ndk

I am trying to build opencv for android. I am almost done, the entire library has built. After the main build I encountered messages about missing JRE path and Android SDK path, but in both cases, Make told me exactly what environment variable needs to be set. However now it cannot find Android NDK and I am not sure how to point it to the right folder.

Here's the error:

```
Override build ABIs for the project face-detection
Override lintOptions for the project face-detection
Override doNotStrip-debug for the project face-detection
Parsing the SDK, no caching allowed
SDK initialized in 0 ms


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':face-detection'.
> NDK not configured.
  Download it with SDK manager.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 52s
VCS Checkout Cache (D:\programming\lib\openCV\opencv\build_clang_64_qt_android_armeabi_v7a\opencv_android\.gradle\vcsWorkingDirs) has not been cleaned up in 0 days
make[2]: *** [opencv_android/opencv/build/outputs/aar/opencv-release.aar] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/java/android_sdk/CMakeFiles/opencv_java_android.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Does [How to install NDK with Android SDK Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46104517/7582247) answer your question?

Comment: Try to set classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0' in `samples/build.gradle`.